# Logitech G15 Keyboard - display api for Delphi

Tags: delphi, hid, logitech

Is there any api/sdk for Delphi to use the G15 Logitech keyboard display?

All I managed to find uses "lgLcdLibWrapper.dll" in between which works only for 32bit projects. Would be nice to have a native solution without involving an extra DLL in between.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Delphi library for the Logitech G15 written by a French author, pseudonym [Delphitness](http://www.delphifr.com/auteur/DELPHITNESS/1622087.aspx).

The communication is based on the JVCL [JvHIDController class](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/), originally written by Robert Marquardt.

Here is the download site : [DelphiFr GESTION-CLAVIER-G15-LOGITEC](http://www.delphifr.com/codes/GESTION-CLAVIER-G15-LOGITECH_49378.aspx) (in French).

This package will enable you to communicate with the Logitech controller without any dll.